# saving outlook attachments with different names in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to save attachments from .msg file into PdF files but with different names. Could anyone please help me out how to proceed further? Here is my code. Error comes on the last line of the code.

```
import win32com.client
import glob
import os

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
path = "C:\\python\\test-email"
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.msg")
working_path = os.getcwd()

for file in allFiles:
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(file)    
count_attachments = msg.Attachments.Count


refno_start = text.find('Student ID') + 8   
newname = "%s.pdf" % text[refno_start + 2:refno_start + 11]

if count_attachments > 0:
    for item in range(count_attachments):  
        attached = msg.Attachments.Item(item + 1)          
        attached.SaveAsFile(working_path +'\\'+newname)
```

Here is the error messgae:

```
  File "email-reader1.py", line 46, in <module>
  attached.SaveAsFile(working_path +'\\'+newname)
  File "<COMObject Item>", line 2, in SaveAsFile
  pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Out    look', 'Cannot save the attachment. File name or directory name is not valid.',None, 0, -2147024773), None)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You should use `os.path.join` for your path generation, e.g.: `attached.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(working_path,newname))`

Comment: @bernie I already tried this and got this error message

Comment: File "email-reader1.py", line 46, in <module>
    attached.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(working_path,newname))
  File "<COMObject Item>", line 2, in SaveAsFile
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Out
look', 'Cannot save the attachment. File name or directory name is not valid.',
None, 0, -2147024773), None)

Comment: Can you print out the result of `os.path.join(working_path,newname)`?

Comment: Yes i can print out the result of os.path.join(working_path,newname)

Comment: Ok thanks. That will help.

Comment: it works in print statement but not in SaveASFile method. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because path you are trying to save to is not valid for Windows. It may contain invalid characters. See [this link on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions) for what is allowed in Windows filenames and paths.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There was problem in the path. T